# Only first line of code executing: Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am making a drawing game in python turtle and only my first line of code is actually being executed. Please check it out and tell me my mistake.

> I wanted to mention that In the code it is supposed to have wsad keys to move the turtle but that is not doing anything on those clicks.

```py
import turtle
turtle.onscreenclick(turtle.goto)
def Up():
    key_events.add('UP')
def W():
      key_events.add('W')
def Down():
    key_events.add('DOWN')
def S():
      key_events.add('S')
def Left():
    key_events.add('LEFT')
def A():
      key_events.add('A')

def Right():
    key_events.add('RIGHT')
def D():
    key_events.add('D')

def move_up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_down():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_left():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_right():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_up_right():
    turtle.setheading(45)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_down_right():
    turtle.setheading(-45)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_up_left():
    turtle.setheading(135)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_down_left():
    turtle.setheading(225)
    turtle.forward(50)
turtle.mainloop()
key_event_handlers = { \
    ('UP',): move_up, \
    ('DOWN',): move_down, \
    ('LEFT',): move_left, \
    ('RIGHT',): move_right, \
    ('RIGHT', 'UP'): move_up_right, \
    ('DOWN', 'RIGHT'): move_down_right, \
    ('LEFT', 'UP'): move_up_left, \
    ('DOWN', 'LEFT'): move_down_left, \
    ('W',): move_up, \
    ('S',): move_down, \
    ('A',): move_left, \
    ('D',): move_right, \
    ('W', 'D'): move_up_right, \
    ('S', 'D'): move_down_right, \
    ('W', 'A'): move_up_left, \
    ('S', 'A'): move_down_left, \
}

key_events = set()
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.title("Draw!")
screen.onkey(Up, "Up")
screen.onkey(Down, "Down")
screen.onkey(Left, "Left")
screen.onkey(Right, "Right")
screen.onkey(W, "W")
screen.onkey(S, "S")
screen.onkey(A, "A")
screen.onkey(D, "D")
def process_events():
    events = tuple(sorted(key_events))

    if events and events in key_event_handlers:
        (key_event_handlers[events])()

    key_events.clear()

    screen.ontimer(process_events, 200)
process_events()
screen.listen()

def red():
  turtle.color("red")
  turtle.color("red")
turtle.onkeypress(red, key="r")
turtle.listen()
def orange():
  turtle.color("orange")
  turtle.color("orange")
turtle.onkeypress(orange, key="o")
turtle.listen()
def yellow():
  turtle.color("yellow")
  turtle.color("yellow")
turtle.onkeypress(yellow, key="y")
turtle.listen()
def green():
  turtle.color("green")
  turtle.color("green")
turtle.onkeypress(green, key="m")
turtle.listen()
def bue():
  turtle.color("blue")
  turtle.color("blue")
turtle.onkeypress(bue, key="b")
turtle.listen()
def indigo():
  turtle.color("indigo")
  turtle.color("indigo")
turtle.onkeypress(indigo, key="i")
turtle.listen()
def violet():
  turtle.color("violet")
  turtle.color("violet")
turtle.onkeypress(violet, key="v")
turtle.listen()
def black():
  turtle.color("black")
  turtle.color("black")
turtle.onkeypress(black, key="n")
turtle.listen()
def clear():
  turtle.clear()
  turtle.clear()
turtle.onkeypress(clear, key="c")
turtle.listen()
def a():
  turtle.turtlesize(1)
  turtle.turtlesize(1)
turtle.onkeypress(a, key="a")
turtle.listen()
def s():
  turtle.turtlesize(2)
  turtle.turtlesize(2)
turtle.onkeypress(s, key="s")
turtle.listen()
def d():
  turtle.turtlesize(3)
  turtle.turtlesize(3)
turtle.onkeypress(d, key="d")
turtle.listen()
def f():
  turtle.turtlesize(4)
  turtle.turtlesize(4)
turtle.onkeypress(f, key="f")
turtle.listen()
def g():
  turtle.turtlesize(5)
  turtle.turtlesize(5)
turtle.onkeypress(g, key="g")
turtle.listen()
def h():
  turtle.turtlesize(6)
  turtle.turtlesize(6)
turtle.onkeypress(h, key="h")
turtle.listen()
def j():
  turtle.turtlesize(7)
  turtle.turtlesize(7)
turtle.onkeypress(j, key="j")
turtle.listen()
def k():
  turtle.turtlesize(8)
  turtle.turtlesize(8)
turtle.onkeypress(k, key="k")
turtle.listen()
def l():
  turtle.turtlesize(9)
  turtle.turtlesize(9)
turtle.onkeypress(l, key="l")
turtle.listen()
def ten():
  turtle.turtlesize(10)
  turtle.turtlesize(10)
turtle.onkeypress(ten, key="z")
turtle.listen()
def p():
  turtle.circle(50)
turtle.onkeypress(p, key="p")
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nothing after `turtle.mainloop()` will execute until the window is closed.  You don't need that line at all.

Comment: Where are you gathering events from?  You realize Turtle handles all that for you, and you just need to assign callbacks for each key, right?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#using-screen-events

Comment: I think you are writing the wrong Python version.  Those look like Python2.x methods, you should be writing with Python3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think whatever resource you're reading from has Python 2.x given as an example.  I haven't seen key events gathered and micromanaged in Python that way in 10 years.

The current template I use to scrbble out a drawing in Turtle looks like this.  I might change bits here and there, but it does alright for now.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from math import sqrt
from random import uniform
import turtle as trt

Width, Height  = 600, 600  ##  no turtle.cfg required
trt ._CFG['width'],  trt ._CFG['height']  = Width *1.02,  Height *1.02  ##  no scrollbars
trt ._CFG['canvwidth'],  trt ._CFG['canvheight']  = Width, Height

turtle, screen  = trt .Turtle(),  trt .Screen()
screen .setworldcoordinates( 0, 0, Width, Height )  ##  lower-left, top-right
screen .title( 'Spiral' )

##  cv  = screen .getcanvas()
screen .tracer( 42, 0 )  ##  Nth screen draw, delay

screen .colormode( 1 )  ##  range 0-1,  defaults 0-255
red, green, blue  = uniform( 0.8, 1 ), uniform( 0.8, 1 ), uniform( 0.8, 1 )
screen .bgcolor( red, green, blue )

##  Pythag.  A squared +B squared  = C squared
diag  = sqrt( (Width *Width) +(Height *Height) )
stepsize  = diag /1000

E, NE, N, NW, W, SW, S, SE  = 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

turtle .hideturtle()
turtle .penup()

red, green, blue  = uniform( 0, 0.2 ), uniform( 0, 0.2 ), uniform( 0, 0.2 )
turtle .pencolor( red, green, blue )
turtle .pensize( stepsize )

turtle .goto( Width *0.5 -stepsize *10,  Height *0.5 +stepsize *20 )
turtle .setheading( NE )
turtle .pendown()

for i in range( 2000 ):  ##  draw spiral
    turtle .forward( stepsize +i /200 )
    turtle .right( 2 )

screen .update()  ##  force an update, for tracer()

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

def right():
    if turtle .heading() != E:  turtle .setheading( E )
    turtle .forward( stepsize )

def up():
    if turtle .heading() != N:  turtle .setheading( N )
    turtle .forward( stepsize )

def left():
    if turtle .heading() != W:  turtle .setheading( W )
    turtle .forward( stepsize )

def down():
    if turtle .heading() != S:  turtle .setheading( S )
    turtle .forward( stepsize )

def click( x, y ):  ##  mouseclicks pass x,y pos that was clicked
    turtle .goto( x, y )
    print( x, y )

screen .onkeypress( right, 'Right' )
screen .onkeypress( up, 'Up' )
screen .onkeypress( left, 'Left' )
screen .onkeypress( down, 'Down' )

screen .onscreenclick( click )

screen .listen()  ##  for mouse & key presses
screen .exitonclick()  ##  binds .bye() to screen click
screen .mainloop()

##  eof  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't archaic Python 2 code, it's aim is perfectly reasonable.  The idea is that if you hit "down" and later "left", you're going to get two lines, one going down and one to the left.  But if you hit "down" and "left" quickly in succesion, you'll get one line, diagonally down and to the left.  It's attempting to consolidate events.

Amid other problems in the code, `process_events()` isn't up to the task.  One clue is that `key_events` is a `set` but order matters when we're drawing (and it gets sorted!)  `key_events` needs to be a `list`.  `process_events()` needs to test for the possibility of a combination move before it processes the input as an individual move.

Below is my rework of the code that I believe is near what was intended.  I've left off some of the colors and cursor size options to make the example smaller.  Note that *case matters* in the letters you type:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

key_events = list()

def up():
    key_events.append('UP')

def W():
    key_events.append('W')

def down():
    key_events.append('DOWN')

def S():
    key_events.append('S')

def left():
    key_events.append('LEFT')

def A():
    key_events.append('A')

def right():
    key_events.append('RIGHT')

def D():
    key_events.append('D')


def move_up():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_down():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_left():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_right():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_up_right():
    turtle.setheading(45)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_down_right():
    turtle.setheading(-45)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_up_left():
    turtle.setheading(135)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move_down_left():
    turtle.setheading(225)
    turtle.forward(50)

def move(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(x, y))
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    screen.onclick(move)

key_event_handlers = { \
    'UP': move_up, \
    'DOWN': move_down, \
    'LEFT': move_left, \
    'RIGHT': move_right, \
    ('RIGHT', 'UP'): move_up_right, \
    ('DOWN', 'RIGHT'): move_down_right, \
    ('LEFT', 'UP'): move_up_left, \
    ('DOWN', 'LEFT'): move_down_left, \
    'W': move_up, \
    'S': move_down, \
    'A': move_left, \
    'D': move_right, \
    ('W', 'D'): move_up_right, \
    ('S', 'D'): move_down_right, \
    ('W', 'A'): move_up_left, \
    ('S', 'A'): move_down_left, \
}

def process_events():
    if key_events:
        events = list(key_events)
        key_events.clear()

        while events:
            event1 = events.pop(0)

            if events:
                event2 = events[0]

                if (event1, event2) in key_event_handlers:
                    (key_event_handlers[(event1, event2)])()
                    events.pop(0)
                    continue

            if event1 in key_event_handlers:
                    (key_event_handlers[event1])()

    screen.ontimer(process_events, 500)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Draw!")

def red():
    turtle.color("red")

screen.onkeypress(red, key="r")

def green():
    turtle.color("green")

screen.onkeypress(green, key="m")

def blue():
    turtle.color("blue")

screen.onkeypress(blue, key="b")

def black():
    turtle.color("black")

screen.onkeypress(black, key="n")

def clear():
    turtle.clear()

screen.onkeypress(clear, key="c")

def original():
    turtle.turtlesize(1)

screen.onkeypress(original, key="a")

def double():
    turtle.turtlesize(2)

screen.onkeypress(double, key="s")

def triple():
    turtle.turtlesize(3)

screen.onkeypress(triple, key="d")

def circle():
    turtle.circle(50)

screen.onkey(circle, key="p")

turtle = Turtle()

screen.onclick(move)

screen.onkey(up, "Up")
screen.onkey(down, "Down")
screen.onkey(left, "Left")
screen.onkey(right, "Right")
screen.onkey(W, "W")
screen.onkey(S, "S")
screen.onkey(A, "A")
screen.onkey(D, "D")

screen.listen()

process_events()

screen.mainloop()
```

Now if you type "S" and "A" at the window, depending on the timing, you'll get different results as it either combines the two moves or does them individually. More combinations could be added.  E.g. along with:

```
('DOWN', 'LEFT'): move_down_left,
```

There could be:

```
('LEFT', 'DOWN'): move_down_left,
```

As the order of these events, if in quick succession, shouldn't matter.  Or trying consecutive events in reverse order could be coded into `process_events()` and the table kept as it is.